# mex compile error: expected expression error at Matlab datatype and function

Tags: matlab, error-handling, compiler-errors, mex

I am starting out mex on linux, so I begin this little code below and try compile:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{ 
    mxArray *inputArrayData;     // array for input array pointers  
}
```

But my compile result is:

```
>> mex firsttry.c
firsttry.c: In function ‘mexFunction’:
firsttry.c:5: error: expected expression before '/' token
```

I have tried with a few other things, and it seems I will get this "expected expression" error at all the lines that involve matlab data and function definition. What could goes wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your file has the extension `.c`, but you are using C++-style comments (introduced with `//`). Rename your file to `firsttry.cpp` and then invoke

```
>> mex firsttry.cpp
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, standard C89 just has "`/*...*/`" to make comment, and mex compiler may use the c compiler just support C89.
To fix this, just simply replace "`//...`" comment in "`/*...*/`" format.